# pulling data from nested json extension API with retforit

Tags: json, api, get, retrofit

I have a nested JSON extension.I am trying to get the data with Retrofit but I have not been successful.I put the API below. I think this API is outputting php (if ı know false,you can warn me). If my URL only consisted of json extension, I could fetch the data, but I don't know how to use this url.
Where am I making a mistake? Could you give information?

//RegionAPI: https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?a=list

```
public class RegionModel {
    @SerializedName("strArea")
    public String strArea;
}

public interface RegionAPI {

    @GET("list.php?a")
    Call<List<RegionModel>> getData();
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView regionTitle;
    ArrayList<RegionModel> regionModels;
    private  String base_URL= "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/";
    Retrofit retrofit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        regionTitle=findViewById(R.id.regionTitle);

        //BölgeAPI: https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?a=list

        //***Retrofit Ve JSON***
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();//gson objesi9
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(base_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        loadData();
    }
    private  void loadData()
    {
        RegionAPI regionAPI = retrofit.create(RegionAPI.class);
        Call<List<RegionModel>> call = regionAPI.getData();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<RegionModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<RegionModel>> call, Response<List<RegionModel>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    List<RegionModel> responseList=response.body();
                    regionModels = new ArrayList<>(responseList);
                    for(RegionModel regionModel : regionModels)
                    {
                        System.out.println(regionModel.strArea);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<RegionModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I think this API is outputting php"_ - The link you provided outputs json, not PHP, if that is what you meant?

Comment: yes I meant that but actually I know that not true.But can use firstly get data using API.Thank you for answer.

Comment: I removed the PHP tag since the question doesn't really have anything to do with PHP (any language could return that data so it's irrelevant to the issue).

Comment: You are right. I think I did not correctly define the data with the nested json extensions and that may be the cause of the problem. @MagnusEriksson